# Vuex - namespace + mapMutations + functions?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

How do I use namespace with mapMutations below?

```
   methods: {
    addTodo() {
      this.$store.commit('todos/addTodo', this.text)
      this.text = ''
    }
   }
```

I tried with:

```
  methods: {
   ...mapMutations('todos', {
      addTodo () {
        this.$store.commit('addTodo', this.text)
        this.text = ''
      }
     })
   }
```

I get this error:

```
commons.app.js:19729 [vuex] unknown mutation type: addTodo
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work in your case because you aren't actually mapping any mutations but adding a function that commits `addTodo` mutation from unknown namespace. Changing
`this.$store.commit('addTodo', this.text)` to `this.$store.commit('todos/addTodo', this.text)` might solve your problem, but still it's not a proper way of using `mapMutations`. `mapMutations` is supposed to let you import your mutations and later call them like any other method. If you want to have any additional logic, like resetting `text` property in your example, you'd have to wrap your commit with another method like in the example below:

```
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations("todos", ["ADD_TODO"]),
    addTodo() {
      this.ADD_TODO(this.text);
      this.text = "";
    }
  }
```

Or with mutation alias:

```
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations("todos", { addTodoMutation: 'ADD_TODO' }),
    addTodo() {
      this.addTodoMutation(this.text);
      this.text = "";
    }
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjvll56oj